# Given the Probability of the Difference between Two Random Variables, what is the Absolute Value of the Difference between Two Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Please suggest any simplifications / known relationships / references for the below.

## Assumptions

$X$ and $Y$ may or may not be independent. It would be interesting to consider both cases separately, if possible.

$\delta \geq 0$. Again if the results apply for any $\delta$, please point out.

## Questions

## 1)

Given,

$$\Pr\left(X-Y\leq\delta\right)=p$$

What can be say about this?

$$\Pr\left(\left|X-Y\right|\leq\delta\right)=??$$

## 2)

How about if the equality is replaced by inequalities? That is given,

$$\Pr\left(X-Y\leq\delta\right) \leq \text{or} \geq p$$

What can be say about this?

$$\Pr\left(\left|X-Y\right|\leq\delta\right) = \text{or}  \leq \text{or} \geq ??$$

## Question Origin / Reference

[Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality)

I am trying to understand, how the one sided estimate below implies the two sided estimate.

The Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality bounds the probability that the empirical distribution function, $F_n$, differs from the true distribution function, $F$, by more than a given constant $ε > 0$ anywhere on the real line. More precisely, there is the one-sided estimate

$$\Pr {\Bigl (}\sup _{{x\in {\mathbb  R}}}{\bigl (}F_{n}(x)-F(x){\bigr )}>\varepsilon {\Bigr )}\leq e^{{-2n\varepsilon ^{2}}}\qquad {\text{for every }}\varepsilon \geq {\sqrt  {{\tfrac  {1}{2n}}\ln 2}},$$

which also implies a two-sided estimate,

$$\Pr {\Bigl (}\sup _{{x\in {\mathbb  R}}}|F_{n}(x)-F(x)|>\varepsilon {\Bigr )}\leq 2e^{{-2n\varepsilon ^{2}}}\qquad {\text{for every }}\varepsilon >0.$$

Please let me know if I am missing something simple or if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Probability is monotone with respect to set containment: If $A \subseteq B$, then $P(A) \le P(B)$.

Comment: @user365239, thanks for pointing this out. So how does this translate to an answer for the questions asked and the various scenarios. If this is present in any reference, please point out.

Comment: @Could someone please clarify, why this is off-topic? Plus I have not found the above questions answered either on this forum or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|X-Y| \le \delta \implies X-Y \le \delta$, we have P$(|X-Y| \le \delta) \le P( X-Y \le \delta)=p$

Comment: please note, it is given that, $X-Y \le \delta$, not the other way around that $|X-Y| \le \delta$ ...  Suppose, $X-Y \le -5$ and say, $ \delta = 2$, but $|X-Y|$ could be more than $\delta$,  Right. Please let me know if I am missing something basic?

Comment: Correct, $X-Y \le \delta$ does not imply $|X-Y| \le \delta$. (e.g. $X-Y = -1$ and $\delta = 1/2$)

Comment: thanks for your patient clarifications. I added a reference that suggests how this question came about. Perhaps, it is possible to get better bounds, as shown in the question. I do not understand how the proofs for those would work.